# How to adjust z-index of divs based on mobile touch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, touch

I'm currently putting together a site project that requires me to have various divs at different z-index's - these z-index's change when the user clicks on a specific div.

I've got this working nicely for desktop use with simple jQuery, for example:

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery("#Div-A").click(function(){
     jQuery('#Div-A').fadeOut('slow');
     jQuery('#Div-B, #Div-C').css('z-index', 9);
  });
});

jQuery(function(){
  jQuery("#Div-D").click(function(){
     jQuery('#Div-A').fadeIn('slow');
     jQuery('#Div-B, #Div-C').css('z-index', 999999);
  });
});
</script>
```

I need to translate this functionality into touch for mobile devices but am seriously struggling.  I'm really sorry if this is a basic or ignorant question but my knowledge of mobile / touch IOS specific coding is very limited.

To be clear - I have three divs, A, B & C - I would like the user to touch div A which would lower the z-index of all three divs, then increase them again at touch end.

If anyone could advise me on this, it would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'll answer my own question - I used something like this:

```
<script>
    $('#DIV-A').bind('touchstart', function(e){
        $('#DIV-B').css('z-index', 9);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>

<script>
    $('#DIV-A').bind('touchend', function(e){
        $('#DIV-B').css('z-index', 9999);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Hope that helps someone!